# call C# method from powershell without supplying optional arguments

Tags: c#, powershell, optional-parameters

I have a c# method I am loading from a dll with optional string arguments that default to `null`.  For example

```
public void foo(string path, string new_name = null, bool save_now = true)
{
    if(name == null)
        new_name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
    ...
    if(save_now)
       Save();
}
```

I want to call this from within a powershell script and not supply a value for `new_name` but one for `save_now`.  As per [this seemingly very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483483/powershell-call-method-with-optional-arguments) I have tried

```
$default = [type]::Missing
$obj.foo($path, $default, $false)
```

but this results in `new_name` being set as `"System.Reflection.Missing"` within the function.

Additionally I tried

```
$obj.foo($path, $null, $false)
```

but this results in `new_name` being set to the empty string, still not `null`.  I could set the default to the empty string, but I was wondering if there was any good way to actually have the default value be used.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could build something to do this with reflection. `GetMethod` returns a `MethodInfo`, which has a `GetProperty` method. It returns a `ParameterInfo` which has `DefaultValue, HasDefaultValue, and IsOptional` properties. So you could develop a PS function, say "InvokeWithNamedParameters" that emulates what VB supports.

Comment: Interesting idea. For me unfortunately the window to try this solution has passed, but maybe someone else with the same question will find this a viable technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No can do in PowerShell.  It doesn't support C#/VB optional parameters.  It is the duty of the language calling the method to provide the default values when the programmer doesn't and PowerShell just doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply omit the optional parameters in the call. I modified your example to run it in PS. For example:

```
$c = @"
    public static class Bar {
        public static void foo(string path, string new_name = null, bool save_now = true)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(path);
            System.Console.WriteLine(new_name);
            System.Console.WriteLine(save_now);
        }
    }
"@

add-type -TypeDefinition $c

[Bar]::Foo("test",[System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value,$false)
```

This generates the following

```
test
False
```

Test was passed explicitly, null is null and had no output, and the save_now evaluated to the default of True.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this still misses my question.  I *do* want to supply a value for the last optional parameter, but not the middle one.  Also, my C# is being imported from a dll, though I don't know if that changes things.

Comment: I see what you mean now. You can use [System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value in v3 which should do what you want. Powershell likes to cast $null to be an empty string. References http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language.nullstring(v=vs.85).aspx and https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/307821/it-isnt-possible-to-pass-null-as-null-into-a-net-method-that-has-a-parameter-of-type-string