# Powershell search regular expression in many Microsoft Word documents

Tags: regex, powershell, ms-word

I have a powershell script to search a string from word files as follows:

```
$searchStr = "ABC/2014/N/123"
$files = gci -path "c:\doc","d:\doc" -include "*.doc*","*.tp?" -recurse 

$word = new-object -ComObject "word.application"
foreach ($file in $files) {

   $doc = $word.documents.open($file.fullname)
   if ($doc.content.find.execute($searchStr)) {

      echo $file.fullname
   }
   $doc.close()
}
```

I want to enhance it to enable regex and insert it before the .execute() as this:

```
set $doc.content.find.text = "[A-Z]{2-5}\/[0-9]{4}\/N\/[0-9]{3}"
set $doc.content.find.matchwildcards = $true
```

However, the properties are read-only as it complains.
So, I try passing them as the parms in .execute()

```
PS C:\> $doc.content.find.execute

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
bool Execute (Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant,
Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant)
```

How can I do it like this?

```
$doc.content.find.execute(Text:="[A-Z]{2-5}\/[0-9]{4}\/N\/[0-9]{3}", matchwildcards:=$true)
```

Many thanks.

It works now, thank you.

```
$searchStr = "CIS\/[0-9]{4}\/N\/[0-9]{3}"
$isRegexp = $true
$files = gci -path "g:\spc","h:\spc" -include "*.doc*","*.tp?" -recurse 

$default = [Type]::Missing
$word = new-object -ComObject "word.application"
foreach ($file in $files) {

   $doc = $word.documents.open($file.fullname, )
   # expression.Execute(FindText, MatchCase, MatchWholeWord, MatchWildcards, 
   #  MatchSoundsLike, MatchAllWordForms, Forward, Wrap, Format, ReplaceWith, 
   #  Replace, MatchKashida, MatchDiacritics, MatchAlefHamza, MatchControl)
   if ($doc.content.find.execute($searchStr,$default,$default,$isRegexp)) {

      echo $file.fullname
   }
   $doc.close()
}
```

Comment: Remember: Word wildcards (and advanced find options) are *not* .NET (and PowerShell) regexes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell Call method with optional arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483483/powershell-call-method-with-optional-arguments)

Comment: Thank you for reminding, Richard. Regexps do work on my Word 2010.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I'm trying which Variant the matchwildcards is.

Comment: It works. Thank you Ansgar. I've updated the script for reference.