# Excel workbooks.saveas() error in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, com

I'm trying to convert .xls files to .xlxs 
I tried many variations of this code but every time i'm facing this error message :

> Exception lors de l'appel de « SaveAs » avec « 2 » argument(s) : « La
>   méthode SaveAs de la classe Workbook a échoué. »    Au caractère
>   C:\temp\xlsx.ps1:18 : 6
>
> - try{$opendoc.saveas($basename, $saveFormat)}
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Here is my code :

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excel.Visible = $false
$saveFormat = "xlOpenXMLWorkbook";

ls c:\temp\*.xls | %{
    $opendoc = $excel.workbooks.open($_.FullName)
    $excel.DisplayAlerts =$false 
    $basename = $_.basename
    try{
        $opendoc.saveas($basename,$saveFormat,$null,$null,$false,$false,"xlNoChange","xlLocalSessionChanges")
      # tried this one and got same error : $opendoc.saveas($basename, $saveFormat)}
    }
    catch{
        $opendoc.close();$excel.quit()
        $_ 
    }
    $opendoc.close();   
}

$excel.quit()
```

do you know the working recipe please ?

Comment: Can't believe this old solution worked for me...
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159887/error-exception-calling-saveas-with-2-arguments-saveas-method-of-workbo :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constants passed into the [`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method usually represent numeric values, not strings. In your case the second parameter probably should be 51 (`xlWorkbookDefault`) as documented [`here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Same goes for the other two strings (`"xlNoChange"`, which [should be 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195297%28v=office.15%29.aspx), and `"xlLocalSessionChanges"`, which [should be 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194803%28v=office.15%29.aspx)). You need to either use the numeric values, or define the constants yourself, e.g.:

```
$xlWorkbookDefault     = 51
$xlNoChange            =  1
$xlLocalSessionChanges =  2
```

Also, you cannot use `$null` for arguments that should retain default values. Use [`[Type]::Missing`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17484660/1630171) instead.

Change this:

```
$opendoc.saveas($basename,$saveFormat,$null,$null,$false,$false,"xlNoChange","xlLocalSessionChanges")
```

into this:

```
$opendoc.SaveAs($basename, 51, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $false, $false, 1, 2)
```