# Dialog box to save file as on existing script

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting, dialog, save-as

I have the following code but I am trying to get it to prompt user with a dynamic dialog box to get the output file to "save as".

```
$pathtsv = "c:\test.txt"
$pathxlsx = "c:\NBP ESP-152 REV F TEMPLATE.xlsx"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Excel.Visible=$true 

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($pathxlsx) # Open Template
$TempWorkbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Opentext($pathtsv) # Open text file in excel

$temp = $excel.Workbooks.Item(2)  #select workbook with text
$temp = $temp.Worksheets.Item(1) #select text worksheet
$CopyRange = $temp.Range("A1:G8") #set range
$CopyRange.Copy()  #copy data

$workbooksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)#sets doc to copy to
$Workbooksheet.activate()
$PasteRange = $workbooksheet.Range("A3:J10") #sets range
$workbooksheet.Paste($PasteRange)#paste data

#save and close the workbook
$Workbook.Close($true)
$Excel.Quit()
while( [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)){}
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

So I tried adding in:

```
$SaveFileDialog = New-Object windows.forms.savefiledialog   
    $SaveFileDialog.initialDirectory = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
```

but it does not seem to be working.  Not sure why, maybe because I am still newbish to powershell scripting.  I just want to get it to end on the save as dialog box, would be fine.  Do I have to cut the end of the original out?  (IE. does this get cut out?

```
$Workbook.Close($true)
$Excel.Quit()
while( [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)){}
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

)

Comment: One question is "where did you add these lines?" Have you investigated `SaveFileDialog.CreatePrompt = True` and `SaveFileDialog.OverwritePrompt = True`?

Comment: Sorry, added it just before the Close dialog.

Comment: Did you add the winforms assembly? e.g. `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` Also did you call `$SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()` to display the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a few things to make this work. First, add a reference to System.Windows.Forms

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

After your copy/paste operations create the dialog and set a couple properties

```
$SaveFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$SaveFileDialog.initialDirectory = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
$SaveFileDialog.Filter = 'All files (*.*)|*.*'
```

This is where you will need to decide what you want to do when showing the dialog. Do you allow the user to cancel, how do you handle empty paths, incorrect extensions, etc... For the sake of example, I am going to simply continue to show it until a path is chosen. I am not endorsing this as a good choice.

```
$dialogResult = $null
while($dialogResult -ne "OK"){
    $dialogResult = $SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()
}
```

You can then access the selected path with the FileName property and perform and checks needed on it

```
$SaveFileDialog.FileName
```

Pass this to the excel workbook's SaveAs method. See this answer for details on this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/25289878/3594883

```
$WorkBook.SaveAs($SaveFileDialog.FileName, 51, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $false, $false, 1, 2)
```

Finally close your workbook and excel. Perform cleanup etc.

Comment: This answer was so thorough I wish i could upvote it.