# Configuring Default Params with .Open with Microsoft Word COM Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, comobject

I'm converting a "hybrid" batch/vbs script to PowerShell and converting the "batch" portion was delightfully straightforward, but I'm struggling a bit with the VBS Conversion.

I can open a word document, but when I try to pass extra params I continually get errors. I want to define each optional param, and ideally, if not passed as a param use default. I read about `ISMISSING` online and something about `System_Call` but I couldn't get it to work so I defined my own "default" values, but they seem all over the place.

Sometimes it was `$true` other times it wants `True` and sometimes I can use `$wdOpenFormatAuto` other times it wants `wdOpenFormatAuto` and other times it requires the enumeration. I feel like I may be just "getting it to work" and want to understand better before I start working more on this project. This is my "open" statement for MS Word as it stands. Can anybody help improve it, help me set `If not Defined, use Default` for most everything.

I found this thread, which mentioned `[Type]::Missing}`, and that worked for the first few params, but when I get to `$PasswordDocument` it throws an error.

[Open a word document and specify encoding with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485112/open-a-word-document-and-specify-encoding-with-powershell)

```
 #Start Word
 $ObjWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
 $ObjWord.Visible  = $OPENUI
 $ObjWord.Documents.Open($FILEPATH)

#.Open
 $FILENAME = $FILEPATH
 IF (!$ConfirmConversions){$ConfirmConversions = $FALSE}
 $ReadOnly = $TRUE
 IF (!$AddToRecentFiles){$AddToRecentFiles = $FALSE}
 IF (!$PasswordDocument){$PasswordDocument = 'str'}
 IF (!$PasswordTemplate){$PasswordTemplate = 'str'}
 $Revert = $FALSE
 IF (!$WritePasswordDocument){$WritePasswordDocument = 'str'}
 IF (!$WritePasswordTemplate){$WritePasswordTemplate = 'str'}
 IF (!$Format){$Format = 'wdOpenFormatAuto'}
 IF (!$Encoding){$Encoding = 'str'}
 IF ($OPENUI -eq "FALSE"){$Visible = $FALSE}ELSE{$Visible = $TRUE}
 IF (!$OpenConflictDocument){$OpenConflictDocument = $TRUE}
 IF (!$OpenAndRepair){$OpenAndRepair = $TRUE}
 IF (!$DocumentDirection){$DocumentDirection = $wdLeftToRight}
 IF (!$NoEncodingDialog){[string]$NoEncodingDialog = 'TRUE'}
 $ObjDoc=$ObjWord.documents.open($FILENAME,$ConfirmConversions,$ReadOnly,$AddToRecentFiles,$PasswordDocument,$PasswordTemplate,$Revert,$WritePasswordDocument,$WritePasswordTemplate,$Format,$Encoding,$Visible,$OpenConflictDocument,$OpenAndRepair,$DocumentDirection,$NoEncodingDialog)
```

Update: I was able to set "Most" to default, but it's such a game of just "trial and error" that I don't like it, I wish I understood what was going on, how to know if a value can accept `missing`.

Here is where I'm at now, with errors listed by values that won't take $missing.

```
 #.Open
 $missing = [System.Type]::Missing
 $str = ''
 $FILENAME = $FILEPATH
 IF (!$ConfirmConversions){$ConfirmConversions = $missing}
 IF (!$ReadOnly){$ReadOnly = $TRUE}
 IF (!$AddToRecentFiles){$AddToRecentFiles = $missing}
 IF (!$PasswordDocument){$PasswordDocument = $str} #Exception setting "Open": Cannot convert the "TRUE" value of type "string" to type "Object". # Doesn't Accept $Missing
 IF (!$PasswordTemplate){$PasswordTemplate = $str} #Exception setting "Open": Cannot convert the "TRUE" value of type "string" to type "Object". # Doesn't Accept $Missing
 IF (!$Revert){$Revert = $False} #Parameter value was out of acceptable range # Doesn't Accept $Missing
 IF (!$WritePasswordDocument){$WritePasswordDocument =  $str} #Exception setting "Open": Cannot convert the "TRUE" value of type "string" to type "Object". # Doesn't Accept $Missing
 IF (!$WritePasswordTemplate){$WritePasswordTemplate =  $str} #Exception setting "Open": Cannot convert the "TRUE" value of type "string" to type "Object". # Doesn't Accept $Missing
 IF (!$Format){$Format = 'wdOpenFormatAuto'} #Command failed # Doesn't Accept $Missing
 IF (!$Encoding){$Encoding = $missing}
 IF ($OPENUI -eq "FALSE"){$Visible = $FALSE}ELSE{$Visible = $TRUE}
 IF (!$OpenConflictDocument){$OpenConflictDocument = $missing}
 IF (!$OpenAndRepair){$OpenAndRepair = $missing}
 IF (!$DocumentDirection){$DocumentDirection = $missing}
 IF (!$NoEncodingDialog){[string]$NoEncodingDialog = 'TRUE'}  #Object reference not set to an instance of an object. # Doesn't Accept $Missing
 $ObjDoc=$ObjWord.documents.open($FILENAME,$ConfirmConversions,$ReadOnly,$AddToRecentFiles,$PasswordDocument,$PasswordTemplate,$Revert,$WritePasswordDocument,$WritePasswordTemplate,$Format,$Encoding,$Visible,$OpenConflictDocument,$OpenAndRepair,$DocumentDirection,$NoEncodingDialog)
```

Interestingly, I can put `PasswordDocument/PasswordTemplate` & `WritePasswordDocument/WritePasswordTemplate` as missing if I OMIT `NoEncodingDialog`, but if I include that param, I have to set the above to a random string???

I do understand that some of these fundamentally are related, so something can't be null if another is set etc etc, but there still seems like I should be able to do this better.

Comment: Check the "Null conditional assignment operator ??=" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7#null-coalescing-assignment-and-conditional-operators.

Comment: I can usually read code and understand it, but that's confusing! I'll have to test it out, but i should have added values can't be set to null

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Where do all of these variables come from in the first place?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm not sure what you mean, but the variables are defined here --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Documents.Open

Comment: No, i meant why are you doing `IF(!$Format){$Format = 'wdOpenFormatAuto'}` and not just `$Format = 'wdOpenFormatAuto'`? There's no automatic variable called `$Format`, and there's no previous mention of it in the code you've posted - so where do you expect `$Format` to come from?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I want any variable to be optionally set if desired, this way it allows the user to set format if desired, but by default its not set

Comment: @EylM what am I supposed to glean from that just curious? How does that fit into my issue/script?