# Do I need to define default values in Excel Range.Find, or can I skip some parameters?

Tags: excel, powershell

I need to do a case insensitive search in an Excel document using [Range.Find.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)

I'm currently using the following command as an attempt do a case insensitive search for any email address returned by https://haveibeenpwned.com

```
    $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find($SearchText, $null, "xlValues", "xlWhole", "xlByRows", 1, $false) #What, After, Lookin, LookAt, SearchOrder, MatchCase
```

It returns:

```
WARNING: [] No public exploits found!
Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
At C:\Users\qqqq\Documents\incidents\Search-PwnAddress.ps1:31 char:9
+         $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find($SearchText, $null, "xlValues" ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

How do I properly do a Range Find so that I can do a case insensitive search?

Comment: You wouldn't pass "xlValues", "xlWhole", "xlByRows" as a string - each of these has a corresponding value - e.g https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xllookat-enumeration-excel

Comment: And I think you'd use `[Type]::Missing` instead of `$null` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483483/powershell-call-method-with-optional-arguments

Comment: Thank you, both answers combined were able to point me in the right direction,  many ways to slice this problem aparrently

Answer (score 0):

From [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) - note that `xlValues`, `xlWhole`, and `xlByRows` are not referred to as `String`s, but constants. They are members of specific `Enumerations` - the  [`XlFindLookIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfindlookin-enumeration-excel), [`XlLookAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xllookat-enumeration-excel) and [`XlSearchOrder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlsearchorder-enumeration-excel) enumerations.

Enumerations have members with descriptive names that reference a specific value - so in this case, you can use the corresponding value as your argument. Trying to pass their names as `Strings` - i.e. `"xlValues"` - will throw a "Type Mismatch" error.

- `xlValues`: -4163
- `xlWhole`: 1
- `xlByRows`: 1

Note also that you should use `[Type]::Missing` instead of `$null`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483483/powershell-call-method-with-optional-arguments) suggests.